# How can I join a table in MySQL, deriving one boolean result based on some criteria?

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have three tables which I am joining in MySQL. For simplicity's sake, let's call them `CUSTOMERS`, `ORDERS` and `NOTES`. My goal is to create one query which is used in a Windows application to generate a list of customers, the *number* of orders they have, and then a flag to indicate if a human has written some notes.

Before I added the requirement of notes, my query to do this was:

```
SELECT c.customer `Customer`, COUNT(o.id) `Order Qty`
FROM customers c
LEFT JOIN orders o ON o.customer_id = c.id
GROUP BY c.customer ASC;
```

Which produces:

```
Customer      Order Qty
--------      ---------
Acme Corp.            2
Bee Inc.              3
```

I'd like add a boolean column to indicate if any *human* entered notes exist. (There are automatically generated notes, which are ignored for this query.)

The `NOTES` table is basically:

```
id               int(3)
customer_id      int(3)
note_datetime    datetime
is_auto          tinyint(1)
note             text
```

Any customer may have any number of notes (one to many relationship), and those notes may be automatically generated (`is_auto` is true) or not.

I'd like to add a column that simply returns true if *any* of the notes for that customer are *not* automatic, letting users know that there are human-entered notes to read.

For this example, ACME (1) has three notes, one of which is not automatic. Bee (2) has two automatic notes:

```
id   customer_id   is_auto
--   -----------   -------
 1             1         1
 2             1         1
 3             1         0
 4             2         1
 5             2         1
```

I've come up with the following query:

```
SELECT
    c.customer `Customer`,
    COUNT(o.id) `Order Qty`,
    IF(SUM(IF(n.is_auto, 0, 1) > 0), TRUE, FALSE) `Human Notes`
FROM customers c
LEFT JOIN orders o ON o.customer_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN notes n ON n.customer_id = c.id
GROUP BY c.customer ASC;
```

This produces:

```
Customer    Order Qty    Human Notes
--------    ---------    -----------
ACME Corp.          6           TRUE  # (6 orders, should be 2)
Bee Inc.            6          FALSE  # (6 orders, should be 1)
```

The problem is that rows from the notes table inflates the number of orders artificially (2 orders multiplied by 3 notes; and 3 orders multiplied by 2 notes). I understand that this is because the LEFT JOIN creates duplicate rows of orders which match multiple rows from the `NOTES` table.

I have not been able to determine a proper way to rewrite this query. What would be a better way to join the notes table so that I get the desired boolean, but avoid extra rows which alter the order count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try just using `exists` instead:

```
SELECT c.customer, COUNT(o.id) as `Order Qty`,
       (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM notes n WHERE n.customer_id = c.id and not n.is_auto)
             THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE
        END) as  `Human Notes`
FROM customers c LEFT JOIN
     orders o
     ON o.customer_id = c.id
GROUP BY c.customer ASC;
```

Otherwise, the number of notes messes up the count for the orders -- as you discovered.

Comment: This looks like a good suggestion, except it doesn't seem to consider the `is_auto` column, thus, I get '1' for every customer rather than just those with notes where `is_auto` is false.

Comment: I was able to get this to work by modifying the condition as follows: `WHERE n.customer_id = c.id AND n.is_auto IS FALSE)` - thanks for pointing me in the right direction.